# MT19937 Generator in C++ and NumPy generate different numbers

Tags: python, c++, numpy, random, random-seed

I am trying to reproduce some C++ code in Python that involves random number generations. The C++ code uses the MT19937 generator as follows:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 generator(1234);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << distribution(generator) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The Python version is (with NumPy 1.23.3)

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.Generator(np.random.MT19937(1234))
for _ in range(10):
    print(rng.random())
```

In both cases, the random seed is set to `1234`. But the two produce different outputs on my machine (macOS 14.0 ARM). The C++ code outputs

```
0.497664
0.817838
0.612112
0.77136
0.86067
0.150637
0.198519
0.815163
0.158815
0.116138
```

while the Python code outputs

```
0.12038356302504949
0.4037014194964441
0.8777026256367374
0.9565788014497463
0.42646002242298486
0.28304326113156464
0.9009410688498408
0.830833142531224
0.6752899264264728
0.3977176012599666
```

Why do the two MT19937 generators produce different sequences despite the same seed? How (if possible) can I make them the same?

Comment: Generators generate integers. How the integer is mapped to a real number in the specified range is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Your problem is you are looking at distributions, they have their own state. You really can only compare the direct output of your twisters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mersenne Twister generator has a defined sequence for any seed that you give it. There are also test values that you can use to verify that the generator you use is conforming.

The distributions are on the other hand *not* standardized and may produce different values in different implementations. Remove the distribution to compare the generators.

---

Note also that `std::mt19937` is a 32 bit generator and it's not obvious (to me) if the numpy version is a 32 or 64 bit generator. You may want to compare `std::mt19937_64` with the numpy implementation - still without involving a distribution of course.

Comment: OP should have only checked the output of the twister, not that of the distributions (which have their own state)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes, that's the message I tried to convey in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard library version of the mersenne twister engine is different from all other versions in how the state is initialized from an integer seed.

You can either use another `mt19937` library in C++ that matches the numpy method (which I think is the way that most people implement mt19937), or you can change how your Python engine is seeded to match:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.random

WORD_SIZE = 32  # The template argument after the type
STATE_SIZE = 624  # The next template argument (Also `len(np.random.MT19937().state['state']['key'])`)
INITIALIZATION_MULTIPLIER = 1812433253  # The last template argument
DEFAULT_SEED = 5489  # A constant

def cpp_seed_mt19937(seed = DEFAULT_SEED):
    state = np.zeros(STATE_SIZE, dtype=np.uint32)
    state[0] = seed
    for j in range(1, STATE_SIZE):
        state[j] = INITIALIZATION_MULTIPLIER * (state[j-1] ^ (state[j-1] >> (WORD_SIZE - 2))) + j
    result = np.random.MT19937()
    result.state = {'bit_generator': 'MT19937', 'state': {'key': state, 'pos': STATE_SIZE - 1}}
    result.random_raw(1)  # Start at index "STATE_SIZE-1" and advance by 1 to advance past the generated state
    return result
    
engine = cpp_seed_mt19937(2)
print(*engine.random_raw(10), sep='\n')
```

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 e(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << e() << '\n';
}
```

These both should produce the same output:

```cpp
1872583848
794921487
111352301
4000937544
2360782358
4070471979
1869695442
2081981515
1805465960
1376693511
```

Now converting these 32 bit numbers into floating point numbers between 0 and 1 will have different results depending on how the algorithm is implemented. You would have to use some way that is standardised to give the same result given the same random number from the mersenne twister.

(Also, `std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);` will not give you the same sequence of numbers on different platforms)

Alternatively, you can have a small portion of C++ code that you call with `ctypes` or otherwise that only generates the random numbers for you, and you can have the rest of the code in Python.

Comment: In my case, it is enough to use the legacy random generator from numpy to make it match c++. The official doc suggests using a `RandomState` object to indirectly call the legacy seeder.